# Type com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcfb`

Tags: android

Facing Error While Using Firebase and Google PlayServices

**Type com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcfb`.
**

And here is my gradle looks

```
dependencies {

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta2'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'

implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

any help

I am using

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```